# Background script in PHP

Tags: php, process, background, task

I need to create a script in php, its created but I need that script run in background because take a 30 minutes procesing diferent files. How can create it, I need run in background and the user can navigate across the site and the script keep running. I try calling the script from ajax async funcition but when change the page of the site the script breaks.

Answer (score -1):

PHP exec("php script.php") can do it.

Comment: This still waits for script.php to complete.